What point minimizes the maximum distance to a given set of points?
Given a set of points $p_1,\ldots p_n$ in the plane, I would like to find a point $q$ such that $$\max_i \operatorname{distance}(q,p_i)$$ is as small as possible.
(a) Is there an efficient algorithm for finding $q$?
(b) Is there a known term for this "min max" point?
I am intersted in answers both for the Euclidean distance and for the taxicab distance.

The Euclidean version is the Smallest-circle problem. The Wikipedia article at that link describes a complicated linear-time algorithm for this.

@TonyK thanks! This appears to answer my question.
